# How to create boxplot with large amount of continuous x-variables and continuous y-variables with R (not ggplot)

Tags: r, boxplot

How to create boxplot with large amount of continuous x-variables and continuous y-variableswith R 
don't use ggplot.
Just like the following figure, the x-axis and y-axis are all continuous numerical variable.
[example boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynCOD.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can plot by `boxplot()` function. From this tutorial :

https://www.r-bloggers.com/box-plot-with-r-tutorial/

r-blogger is good for your start learning R. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have a multiple options:

- http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/boxplot.html
- https://www.r-bloggers.com/box-plot-with-r-tutorial/
- https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/boxplot.html
- https://plot.ly/r/box-plots/

Comment: Sorry the question is misleading, I have modified the question

Answer (score 0):

Boxplot between two variables

```
 boxplot(xval~yval)
```

I would advise a scatterplot though

Now suppose I want to reduce the number of boxplots, I would convert the x axis into some mind of bins using cut

cut divides the range of x into intervals and codes the values in x according to which interval they fall

`newyval=cut(yval,20)` for 20 bins

then

```
boxplot(xval~newyval)
```

Comment: Sorry the question is misleading, I have modified the question